# Next.js - Load the same date on all pages (SSR)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm looking for a solution to display data (data that are saved in my database, in a "parameters" table) on all pages of my website.

So I want an Ajax function to be called (server side) on every page change.
But I want this data to be loaded on the server side (for SEO, etc.).
So far I just managed to do this, but on the client side... I did this using the useEffect, and using a Context, and wrapping my Layout component in my Context's Provider.
But this does not suit me. Because for SEO it's not great, and above all, with each change of page, it leaves a delay to display this data.

Do you have an idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call an API in your _app.js file

```
    // _app.js
    MyApp.getInitialProps = async context => {
       const componentProps = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
          .then(response => response.json());
       return { props: { ...componentProps }}
    };
```

Comment: Yes, good. Thanks very much.